# How can I connect a WPF application to the Azure SignalR Service

Tags: c#, azure, signalr

I am working on a WPF application that I'd love to connect to the Azure SignalR Service that I created an instance of. There isn't anything that I can find that directly addresses this scenario. I can setup a BlazorServer and connect that way. But, i'd rather not host the server and use Azure.

Any idea of how that might look?

For example, I attempt this and it does not work:

```
HubConnection? connection;
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("https://scisachat.service.signalr.net/client/?hub=draftchat") 
                .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                .Build();

connection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
       var newMessage = $"{user}: {message}";
       Messages.Items.Add(newMessage);
       Messages.Items.Add($"Connected on {DateTime.Now}");
    });
});

try
{
   await connection.StartAsync();
   Messages.Items.Add("Connection Started");
   openConnection.IsEnabled = false;
   sendMessage.IsEnabled = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Messages.Items.Add(ex.Message);
}
```

I tried to connect to the Azure SignalR service as opposed to my chat hub on a localhost. It fails spectacularly.

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: I get a response message that says:

"Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)"